# Tomcat class not found & there is the class in the path WEB-INF\lib

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, webserver

I copied an app from server, then deployed on Tomcat6 (same as the server), but I always get the error! I tried to reinstall Tomcat, but the error is still the same.

**error1:**

```
            2011-4-12 21:36:16 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
2011-4-12 21:36:16 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
2011-4-12 21:36:21 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Marking servlet AdminServlet as unavailable
2011-4-12 21:36:21 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

严重: Error loading WebappClassLoader
  context: /portal
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@1eed786
 org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4387)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:585)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
2011-4-12 21:36:21 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup

严重: Servlet /portal threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4387)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:585)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
2011-4-12 21:36:54 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

严重: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1493)
    at pde.ams.AmsGlobals.loadProperties(AmsGlobals.java:82)
    at pde.ams.AmsGlobals.getAmsPropertys(AmsGlobals.java:47)
    at pde.ams.AmsEngine.initialize(AmsEngine.java:77)
    at pde.ams.AmsEngine.<init>(AmsEngine.java:61)
    at pde.ams.AmsEngine.getInstance(AmsEngine.java:45)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:90)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at pde.ams.filters.AmsFilter.doFilter(AmsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
2011-4-12 21:37:07 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
```

**error2:**

```
    严重: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class pde.ams.ContextListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pde.ams.ContextListener.contextDestroyed(ContextListener.java:15)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4846)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:1290)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:323)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.stop(StandardEngine.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:735)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:619)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
2011-4-12 21:37:07 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
2011-4-12 21:37:07 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()

   desc:there are  the classes that could not found by tomcat still in the path /web_inf/lib
```

Question1: What's wrong with it?

Question2: Is there any relation between the error1  and error2?

ok this is compete stack trace

Comment: When you copied the app, did you remove the sources generated by any `.jsp` pages? They are likely to refer classes that don't exist if the server doesn't run tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question1: What's wrong with it?

The first error looks like a bug in the webapp or its configuration.  Tomcat is reporting that something (e.g. one of the servlets) is not tidying up correctly when the webapp is shutdown.  If this is left unfixed, your webserver is liable to run out of memory after a few webapp restarts.

The second error is complaining that some class can't be found.  This is probably a web server or webapp configuration error of some kind.

In both cases, it would help if you showed us the complete stack traces.

> Question2: Is there any relation between the error1 and error2?

Probably not.

---

A little bit of digging tells me that you are likely to find `org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet` in a JAR file called `axis-x.y.jar` or something like that (see http://findjar.com/class/org/apache/axis/transport/http/AdminServlet.html for a complete list)

For `org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder` look for a file like `jdom-x.y.jar` (see http://findjar.com/class/org/jdom/input/SAXBuilder.html for a complete list)

The second error is different to the error you originally reported, but it is still a bug in the webapp.  This one could be a consequence of your first error; i.e. it is assuming that the servlet started up properly.

You need to take a look at you webapp as installed on Tomcat and see if the Axis and JDOM JARs are in WEB-INF/lib.  If not, go back to the server you copied the webapp from and look the webapp there ... and in the server's common library area.  (You don't say what kind of server you are copying from ...)

Comment: thank u ,i edit the question agian ,show the complete stack traces ,i still can't  resolove the problem .

Comment: thank u vey much! i found the reason just because the jar in the lib  is broken! maybe some thing wrong when i copy the jar to myeclipse webapp. when i change to user netbeans ,it report the jar file is broken. thank u very much.